# Win7 pro для компьютерного клуба или одноплатного пк

Tags: windows

Мне нужно как-то настроить win7 professional таким образом, чтобы юзеру было доступно только запустить одну единственную программу и больше ничего. Ближайший пример из памяти - такое я видел когда-то давно в компьютерном клубе. Я даже не понял тогда, какая там была операционная система. Она была ни на что не похожа. Кроме того нужно чтобы админ мог загрузить этот комп с нормальными настройками и всеми возможностями стандартной win7.
Спасибо!

Comment: Не оно? https://hippocat73.livejournal.com/74203.html

Comment: Вы можете использовать Групповые политики Windows или Программу контроля доступа (AppLocker) для ограничения доступа пользователя к программам и файлам. Вы также можете создать отдельный пользовательский профиль для данного пользователя, в котором будут ограничены права и настройки. Важно сохранять оригинальный администраторский профиль для возможности восстановления настроек.

Comment: "Я даже не понял тогда, какая там была операционная система. Она была ни на что не похожа. " - если ни на что не похоже, то это вообще мог быть какой-нибудь Linux.